# FFmpeg - Can't use YADIF filter with CONCAT

Tags: ffmpeg, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to use FFMPEG in MacOS to de-interlace a video while joining it with a bumper to no avail. Any ideas?

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i //volumes/DMR_30/BUMPERS/YUYU_BUMPER_5994_V2.mov -i //Volumes/DMR_38/SUMMERSIDE_38/SNOW/SNOW_SUBS_1080p_25PAL.mov\> -filter_complex  "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][0:0]yadif=0:-1:0; [a]" \[base] -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -codec:v libx264 -x264opts "keyint=48:min-keyint=48: no-scenecut" -s 1920:1080 -aspect 16:9 -vb 40M -minrate 40M -maxrate 40M -bufsize 40M -acodec aac -strict -2 -ab 320k ~/desktop/CONCAT+TEST.mp4
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM
3.5svn) configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda   libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100   libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101   libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100   libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100   libavfilter     6. 65.100 / 
6. 65.100   libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0   libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100   libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100   libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '//volumes/DMR_30/BUMPERS/YUYU_BUMPER_5994_V2.mov':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2016-09-12T22:32:25.000000Z   Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53342 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-12T22:32:25.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(progressive), 1920x1080, 51801 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9,
59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 5994 tbn, 5994 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-09-14T19:22:03.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.1 : stereo Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '//Volumes/DMR_38/SUMMERSIDE_38/SNOW/SNOW_SUBS_1080p_25PAL.mov':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2   Duration: 01:19:05.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 105644 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 104108 kb/s, SAR 159:160 DAR 53:30, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25025 tbn, 25025 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : qt_apcn
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : DataHandler [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9afe5003c0] Unable to parse graph description substring: "yadif=0:-1:0; [a]"
Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument
```

Comment: Could you break those code parts apart to make it more clear what is the command and what are the outputs?

Comment: hey @music2myear does this help at all? I'm a bit new to this... Thanks for taking the time to take a look.

Comment: It's a little better. I'd guess the formatting of the input and output would make it difficult for the various markup options to function consistently. But they may be worth looking at for further edits. The Blockquote and Code markups, in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax, at least as pasted, is wrong.

```
ffmpeg -i //volumes/DMR_30/BUMPERS/YUYU_BUMPER_5994_V2.mov -i //Volumes/DMR_38/SUMMERSIDE_38/SNOW/SNOW_SUBS_1080p_25PAL.mov \
 -filter_complex  "[1]yadif=0:-1:0,setsar=1[mp]; \
                   [0:v][0:a][mp][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -codec:v libx264 -x264opts "keyint=48:min-keyint=48: no-scenecut" \
 -aspect 16:9 -vb 40M -minrate 40M -maxrate 40M -bufsize 40M \
 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ab 320k ~/desktop/CONCAT+TEST.mp4
```